# LazyList in Scala

Tags: scala

Assume that we have the following LazyList definition:

```
val fibs: LazyList[BigInt] = BigInt(0) #:: BigInt(1) #::
fibs.zip(fibs.tail).map(pair => pair._1 + pair._2)
```

My question is how is that executed, because this definition says that we take the tail and we do computation for each pair (from the zip). But if we want to calculate element with index 10 we already have values for ...8, 9. So the question is... is this somehow optimized, or for each next element we go through all the pairs?

Comment: You can add a `println` inside the `map` to check. **LazyLists** are memonized, they remember already computed elements.

Comment: The [ScalaDocs page](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.html) uses that same `fibs()` algorithm to illustrate, in great detail, concepts of memoization, holding on to the head, infinite regression, immutability, etc., and how they apply to `LazyList`. The answer is yes, memoization occurs as long as something holds on to the head of the list.

Comment: @jwvh ok that would be an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on-

1. LazyList is essentially a LinkedList, this would mean that in order to access 10th element you'd have to go through all first.
2. The `#::` operator/method essentially ends up creating a new class, this is the library code-

   ```
   implicit def toDeferrer[A](l: => LazyList[A]): Deferrer[A] = new Deferrer[A](() => l)

   final class Deferrer[A] private[LazyList] (private val l: () => LazyList[A]) extends AnyVal {

     /** Construct a LazyList consisting of a given first element followed by elements
       *  from another LazyList.
       */
     def #::[B >: A](elem: => B): LazyList[B] = newLL(sCons(elem, l()))

     /** Construct a LazyList consisting of the concatenation of the given LazyList and
       *  another LazyList.
       */
     def #:::[B >: A](prefix: LazyList[B]): LazyList[B] = prefix lazyAppendedAll l()
   }
   ```

The order of object creation then would be-

1. Lazily wrapped in Function0 `fibs.zip(fibs.tail).map(pair => pair._1 + pair._2)`
2. Afterwards we have the cons operator `#::` available, we attach a new head `BigInt(1)`
3. Lastly, we again attach a new head to the LinkedList `BigInt(0)`, now our recursive structure is ready.
4. Again everything is still constructed lazily, that's why we don't end up dereferencing null

When we call head, we start unwrapping and then the laziness starts taking action.

Furthermore, `LazyList` internally uses this State structure to model the head and tail

```
private sealed trait State[+A] extends Serializable {
  def head: A
  def tail: LazyList[A]
}
```

and this structure is what it memoizes on first access for each of the elements.

```
private lazy val state: State[A] = { ... }
```

Comment: But the question is if the list is fully 'recreated' each time we access next element?

Comment: Cool, accepted answer! I really would like to know more about memoization. For instance I've seen that it is possible to create own memoize function to make your recursive function faster. This is a new concept for me I am not quite familiar with the syntax also.

Comment: See if this helps, you can pass this any function and it would return it's memoized variant
https://github.com/gagandeepkalra/category-theory/blob/master/src/main/scala/memoize/Memoize.scala